# How to populate infinitley comment reply mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have added a reply on post comments on my website and now I have a problem how to populate deep reply. I always use this method `.populate('comments.authorid', ['username', 'avatarUrl'])` but when the user reply on reply, there is a problem.

Do you have any idea how to solve it? I'm looking for something that allows populate all fields by name

Update!

Ok I have found the problem. So in the commentSchema I use `comments:[this]` It does not work. I need a way to nest CommentSchema in comments field.

```js
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  authorid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
    required: true,
  },
  Date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  comments:[this],
  like:[{
    user:{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Users",
    }
  }]
});
```

```js
const userPost = new Schema ({

body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    text: true,
    minlength: 4,
},
file:{
  type: String
},
postTags: [{
  type: String
}],
authorid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
    required: true,
},
Date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
like:[{
  user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users",
  }
}],
comments: [
    CommentSchema.schema
    ],
});
```